# Flutter bottom navigation bar title color

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i need a help to change color of title, when its selected. Now its blue, but i wanna change it to black. Here is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem> [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(  
        activeIcon: Icon(
          Icons.store,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.store,        
          color: Colors.grey,    
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Ponuky',
          style: GoogleFonts.josefinSans(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this two line after items closing bracket

selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
unselectedItemColor: Colors.blue,

```
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem> [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(  
        activeIcon: Icon(
          Icons.store,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.store,        
          color: Colors.grey,    
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Ponuky',
          style: GoogleFonts.josefinSans(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          ),
        ),
      ),],
      selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
```

Answer (score 0):

`title` in `BottomNavigationBarItem` is deprecated right now, you have to use `label` instead of `title` and style it using properties.

[How to style BottomNavigationBarItem label](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64468586/7389051)