# The argument type 'Text' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this issue after after updating from old version (Title) to Label in the bottom nav bar. Here's a sample of the code:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(iconname.shop),
            label: Text(
              'Store',
              style: tabLinkStyle,
            )),
```

Comment: The answer provided by anilcngz is correct. After he replied I found this article with a full description: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/bottom-navigation-title-to-label

Answer (score 2):

label is accepting String?, not a widget, so your code should be as following:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(conname.shop),
          label: 'Store',
        ),
```

Comment: Will style work the same here as it does with Text? Or should I instead of Label use Widget?

Comment: You can style selectedItem, unselectedItem etc. in BottomNavigationBar widget, you can see examples in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Comment: Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468586/how-to-style-bottomnavigationbaritem-label/64469096#64469096