# The named parameter 'title' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

```
return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text(  
            'Home',
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF545454)),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.heart),
          title: Text(
            'Wish List',
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF545454)),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingBag),
          title: Text(
            'Cart',
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF545454)),
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.dashcube),
          title: Text(
            'Dashboard',
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF545454)),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Color(0xFFAA292E),
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

BottomNavigationBarItem doesn't have a `title` parameter anymore. It should be something like this now:

```
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.heart),
      label: 'Wish List',
    ),
```

For styling, you can see an old answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64469096/13263384